# Windows speech c++

Tags: c++, speech

Hy my name is Joey and i would like to know if there is a way to use speech in C++ if so can someone point me to references and books deeply appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [Windows Text-To-Speech API](http://www.microsoft.com/speech/speech2007/speechdevarticle.mspx) - a COM-based API that can be used from C++. You would need to download the Speech API 5.3 SDK as a [DVD ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF) or through a [guided install](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC) of only the components you need..

As a side note, there's also a managed speech API in .Net 3.0 residing in the System.Speech namespace.